# PayPal exception with .NET API: Stream was not readable

Tags: paypal

Trying to process payments, but my customers are getting an exception. When I step through the payment process, I see this exception when I attempt to obtain an Access Token using the OAuthTokenCredential method:

Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Stream was not readable.

This was working just a few days ago. I did update some things on my site, but have not touched the PayPal code, nor have I changed the ClientId and ClientSecret credentials. Any thoughts on what might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: After I posted the question above, I checked my project's NuGet references and found that the PayPal APIs were just updated a couple days ago. Apparently, there were breaking changes. Once I updated those assemblies things started working again.

Answer (score 2):

Something broke on PayPal's end and they had to release an update to their PayPal REST API. Use NuGet to download the updated API references and it fixes the issue.

Comment: I have this issue, and have updated, but it did not fix it, any other ideas?

Comment: When you updated, did you remove the reference and re-add it? I believe that is what I had to do to get it to work.

Comment: I still receive this error despite updating to the latest version of the assemblies. Out of 300 transactions it occurred approximately 10 times. Normally it happens to the same customer repeatedly before finally accepting the transaction.

Comment: I am just about to start using this API again...I will let you know in the coming week or two if we experience the same thing or not.