# C#.net PayPal Rest API Stream not readable error

Tags: oauth, paypal, oauth-2.0

I have downloaded PaypalRestAPI SDK, replace client id and secret with mine and try to generate token. but it is saying "Stream is not readable".

Comment: Sounds like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299954/paypal-exception-with-net-api-stream-was-not-readable?rq=1) issue...